# Making sin 'arc' with exact length

Tags: python, math

I have a relatively simple question which I don't even know how to formulate to google it...

Say, I have an array of variable length, for example:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

While iterating through such a loop, I want to recieve values:

```
[0, 1,   2,   3,   4,   5, 6]
[0, 0.3, 0.7, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 0]
```

So basically, I need value from 0 to 1, going up until it hits the middle, and then going down. Either something simple, or with ease-in ease-out, I don't really care much. So it can be either sin with defined length of an arc, or just some other hack... Interested in every approach to this.

I'm talking about the id of a for loop.

```
for x in range(0,6):
 y = ?
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
Values ARE irrelevant!

Comment: Do the values on the array affect the result? If it was an array of `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` would it be the same as `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If the values of the array, but the length matters, have you tried dividing the array in half and then finding the step's needed to go from 0 to 1?

Comment: What's the logic behind your increasing? is there any specific interval?

Comment: No, values are irrelevant. While iterating through array, depending on current position in the array, I need a value to go up and down in an arc.

Comment: `y = x` or `y = 0` work if the values are irrelevant. Take a step back rather, there is the movement through the array and the computation, which of the two gives you problems?

Comment: "every approach to this" is far to broad. `sin` is fine for this.  But what do you mean by "defined length of an arc"?  The arc length of the `sin` curve isn't algebraically computable, as I recall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values in the array are irrelevant, then the output should be `sin( currentPositionOfArray*PI / (lengthOfArray-1) )`. In this case, however, make sure the array's length is `> 1`.

This means that for your array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, you get the sin of `[0, PI/6, PI/3, PI/2, 2PI/3, 5PI/6, PI]`, which is `[0, 0.3, 0.7, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 0]`

Comment: array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

for x, val in enumerate(array):
    y = math.sin( x*math.pi / (len(array)-1) )
    print x, y

For some reason this gives me:
0 0.0; 
1 0.5; 
2 0.866025403784; 
3 1.0; 
4 0.866025403784; 
5 0.5; 
6 1.22464679915e-16;

Comment: How is `math.sin(3) = 1`? My small java (don't have python in this laptop) program prints `[0.0, 0.49, 0.86, 1.0, 0.86, 0.49, 0.0]`

Comment: My code btw is `for(int i=0; i<7; i++){ System.out.println(Math.sin( i*Math.PI / (7-1) )); }`

Comment: Well, Weird.
`for x, val in enumerate(array):
    a = x*math.pi
    b = (len(array)-1)
    y = math.sin( a / b )
    print x, a, b, y`

Prints:

`0 0.0 6 0.0
1 3.14159265359 6 0.5
2 6.28318530718 6 0.866025403784
3 9.42477796077 6 1.0
4 12.5663706144 6 0.866025403784
5 15.7079632679 6 0.5
6 18.8495559215 6 1.22464679915e-16`

Comment: Ah, i misred you answer, sorry. The values are correct! If your issue is `1.22464679915e-16`, that value is extremely close to `0`. It gets like that because PI is an infinite number, and you lose precision when calculating its `sin`

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use

```
y = (x*(6-x))/9
```

or generally for a segment from 0 to n

```
y = (4*x*(n-x))/(n**2)
```

Taking the square of that gives a start from and end to velocity zero.

Comment: You assume eventually `x=n`, so `n=arrayLength-1`

Comment: No, not exactly that, `n=arrayLength-1`

Comment: Typo, my bad. Maybe describe `n` in your answer